# Docker compose error with docker-engine version

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've installed `docker-engine` and `docker-compose`. I have only one installation of both on my system.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
```

However, when I trying to execute `docker-compose build`, i've got this error:

```
ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater.
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is pretty simple:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4.1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
 web:
    build: .
    command: bin/rails s -e development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/myproject
```

I've have no clues on what is going on.

UPD: My system is Fedora 23.
Output of `docker info`

```
$ docker info
Containers: 9
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 9
Images: 83
Server Version: 1.11.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:6-1188585-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 5.935 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 13.71 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 6.803 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.141 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.109 (2015-09-22)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 4.4.9-300.fc23.x86_64
Operating System: Fedora 23 (Workstation Edition)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 5.7 GiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: 22QE:VZIY:26E3:WMVR:FH3Q:VYTS:FPJX:LFJ3:DHPK:EAZZ:ZDHP:56Q3
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Comment: As commented in The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose, can you check if `COMPOSE_API_VERSION` is set anywhere in your shell environment?

Comment: @VonC no, i don't have this variable.

Comment: What platform are you running on? (Linux, Mac/Win under Machine or Mac/Win native?) Can you post the output of `$ docker info`?

Comment: @JHarris updated my post.

Comment: Is your `web` service defined at the top-level? Or is that just SO formatting?

Comment: @JHarris just formatting. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, WTF is going on, but now it works.
I didn't do ANYTHING >_<

@VonC, @JHarris, sorry guys for wasting your time. If I'll figure out the problem, I will update my answer.

However, now I can't catch this error again.